# spring boot test does not scan subpackages

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot

I'm coding with spring(boot, data, test...) and I'm using TDD, my tests are under src/test/java inside specifics packages just like my normal classes. When I run tests, Spring does not execute my JUnit tests inside the subpackages. For exemple: ApplicationTests runs without any problem but JUnitTest does not. What should I do? I'm getting started with Spring and I don't know what to do. The package organization is bellow:

```
com
+- example
    +- myproject
        +- ApplicationTests.java
        |
        +- domain
        |   +- JUnitTest.java
```

ApplicationTests are annoted with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and @SpringBootTest

Any help?

Comment: How exactly are you running your tests? Spring doesn't run your tests, your build system or IDE will do that. What build system do you use? How is it configured?

Comment: Hi, I just run maven. I'm using Spring Tool Suite. When I run mvnw file whith the params test -B the same thing happen, just the class under the main package runs, tests inside subpackages does not run.

Comment: Mario, which IDE are you using? I have been using IntelliJ, and whenever I want to run all the tests, I simply right click the test package (which you have) and select "run all tests". That always work without any additional configuration. See if you can do something simillar to that on your IDE of choice.